# JNI cannot find dependent libraries

Tags: java-native-interface, btrieve

My java 1.5 application (running on Windows 7) accesses btrieve files, from Pervasive Software (PVSW). I use a JAR file supplied by PVSW, named psql.jar. This JAR accesses several DLLs. Most of the time my application runs without error, but sometimes, on the initial load of the JAR file I get a java exception:

jnibtrv.dll - cannot find dependent libraries

Restarting the computer fixes the problem - until the next time it happens.
I have profiled my application with "Dependency Walker" (version 2.2). The error did not occur during profiling, but it also didn't even show that file jnibtrv.dll was loaded.

How can I find what dependent library is missing?

Comment: Check the PVSW.LOG file to see if there are any errors loading files.  My guess is that you might have an older version of one of the Pervasive DLLs and it causes the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and forgive me if this is a stupid comment, but are you saying that the DLL is never loaded? If not then why does my application work most of the time without error? Also, where is this PVSW.LOG file located? I can't find it.

Comment: I'm not saying that the DLL is never loaded.  I'm saying that since Pervasive / Btrieve has been around for a long time, sometimes older versions of DLLs interfere with the working version.  I'm using PSQL v11.  My PVSW.LOG is located in C:\ProgramData\Pervasive Software\PSQL\logs.  What version of PSQL are you using?

Comment: I don't have folder C:\ProgramData\Pervasive Software. I believe I am using version 9 (nine)

Comment: It might be in C:\PVSW\BIN or maybe in C:\WINDOWS.

Comment: @mirtheil, I won't be back at work until Sunday morning, so I'll search then. Thanks.